# how do i gain acceess to a drive that owned by deleted user on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, accounts

I did some trial on command line and creating a user account from it, then I logged off and logging to that newly created account (let us call it newaccount). Then I mounted one of my drive (I named it as LOSSProp) from it. After that, I returned to my account (myaccount), and then deleted newaccount. But then I lost my permission to mount mydrive and I can't open it anymore. Then I googling for a while, looking for a solution to fix it, I had tried

```
sudo chown -R username:username /media/mydrive
```

and using GUI by nautilus in sudo mode.
But still I can't change its owner, it still owned by newaccount which I had deleted it.

How do I fix it?

Comment: did you try this from within a root shell? `$ sudo su -` and `# chown -R username:username /media/mydrive` ? what kind of file system is that?

Comment: Your drive may still be mounted by `newaccount`. Reboot your machine in order to completely dismount all drives, and try again to mount your drive using Nautilus (you shouldn't have to use `sudo` or `gksudo`).

Comment: I had rebooted my machine and the problem is solved.Thanks, all for give me some advices.